# Find the right Regex or approach to split a large text file to chunks

Tags: java

I would like to split a large text file to chunks while reading with a FileReader/BufferedReader. Each chunk will be processed separately in my downstream code (i.e generating a HashMap of information for each chunk). In order to do this, at first, I need to find a pattern to define how one chunks looks like. 
Maybe someone can help me out here.

This is how the general structure of my file looks like ("//" and "\\" are not part of the file):

//

```
    Car: Oldtimer

     Ford Model T - 1908    
     Chevrolet Bel-Air - 1956
     Mercedes-Benz W 198 - 1954 

    Car: Compact Car

     Toyota iQ - 2008
     Volkswagen Polo V - 2009
     Audi A1 - 2010 

    Car: Special Car

     Bat Mobile - 1966
     Black Beauty - 1966    
     K.I.T.T. - 1982

   Total: 3

                       //
```

One chunk should start with "Car: ABC" and end before the next "Car: XYZ" entry.
There is always one blank line before and after each "Car: ABC" entry. The file ends with "Total: n".
Just for illustration, the first chunk of my sample file will be:

//

```
Car: Oldtimer

 Ford Model T - 1908    
 Chevrolet Bel-Air - 1956
 Mercedes-Benz W 198 - 1954 

                           //
```

So far, I tried REGEX matching to match any entries between the "Car:"-tags using `Pattern.compile("Car:\\s(.*)Car:\\s")` However, this approach would leave out each even chunk , e. g. the chunk starting with "Car: Compact Car".
Maybe you know other or better approaches to give each chunk an identity.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a job for a state machine!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: rather than using regex in this situation, simply u can read the file using any Steram and then store the data in the HashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting delimiter to "Car:|Total:" RE might be a solution; You have chunk in each .next() call.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
sc.useDelimiter("Car:|Total:");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a very smart and handy solution.

Answer (score 0):

A `Car` is an Object. So make a class for it. Then, you know once you've seen a `Car` type, you know what it's type is, then use a simple `String.split` to parse the file.

### Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
  public static class Car {
    public String type;
    public String name;
    public int year;
    
    public Car(String type, String name, int year) {
      this.type = type;
      this.name = name;
      this.year = year;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("Car: %s\tName: %s\tYear: %d", type, name, year);
    }
  }
  
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("cars.txt")));
    
    Map<String, Set<Car>> carMap = makeCars(br);
    
    for(String key : carMap.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(key);
      for(Car car : carMap.get(key)) {
        System.out.println(car);
      }
    }
   }
  
  public static Map<String, Set<Car>> makeCars(BufferedReader br) throws Exception {
    String carType = null;
    Set<Car> carList = null;
    Map<String, Set<Car>> carMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Car>>();
    int linecounter = 0;
    
    while(br.ready()) {
      String line = br.readLine();
      linecounter++;
      
      if(line.contains("Car:")) {
        String[] typeSplit = line.split(": ");
        if (typeSplit.length != 2) System.err.format("Error reading file on line %d%n", linecounter);
        carType = typeSplit[1].trim();
        carList = new HashSet<Car>();
        carMap.put(carType, carList);
        continue;
      }
      String[] carSplit = line.split(" - ");
      if (carSplit.length != 2) continue;
      
      Car newCar = new Car(carType, carSplit[0].trim(), Integer.parseInt(carSplit[1].trim()));
      carList.add(newCar);
    }
    
    return carMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: You gave me a full working class here. Big thanks for your effort. It also helped me to simplify some code of mine (+1 from me).

Comment: My pleasure. Too often people go "Regex, Regex, Regex" because it's so powerful - a swiss army knife is powerful too but sometimes all you really want is a regular knife because all you're doing is slicing bread.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
(Car:).*?(?=Car:|Total:)
```

Comment: "This works for me:" Did you test it with the Matcher class? I am still struggling to make it work for me.