# Seperate data in a csv file that is in between 2 different asterisks using Java

Tags: java, csv

I am still fairly new to Java and trying to learn. I am trying to create a program, in Java, that will be able to read a `.CSV` file that I have in my `C:\` Drive and once it is read I want it to separate the data into a newer `.CSV` file when they are between the comments of the `CSV`.

For example we have the original `CSV` data file as follows:

```
 *File A
 *Name, Address, City, Country, Zip
 "John","123 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Jane","456 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Smith","789 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 *File B
 *Name, Address, City, Country, Zip
 "Jose","123 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Brandon","456 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Mike","789 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 *File C
 *Name, Address, City, Country, Zip
 "Kathy","123 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Jai","456 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Michael","789 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
```

So basically I am trying to have something that will be able to read the `CSV` file, look for the prefix of `*File`, in the `CSV` file, and then will be able to create new files which will have everything in between. For example:

```
 CSV1:
 *Name, Address, City, Country, Zip
 "John","123 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Jane","456 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Smith","789 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"

 CSV2:
 *Name, Address, City, Country, Zip
 "Jose","123 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Brandon","456 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Mike","789 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"

 CSV3:
 *Name, Address, City, Country, Zip
 "Kathy","123 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Jai","456 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
 "Michael","789 Main Street","NY","USA","12345"
```

I was able to find something and able to read the `CSV` file but just don't know how to divide it yet. The following is the code for reading the file:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class csvReader
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            //Get scanner instance
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Personal_Info.csv"));

            //Set the delimiter used in file
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");

            //Get all tokens and store them in some data structure
            //I am just printing them on the screen
            while (scan.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.print(scan.next() + ",");
            }
              System.out.println("\n*************Process Complete*************");
            //Close the scanner 
            scan.close();
        }//End Main
    }//End Class
```

Comment: take a look at this answer, it splits the file into pieces - you could do something similar and simply create new files from the pieces...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283770/find-the-right-regex-or-approach-to-split-a-large-text-file-to-chunks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab line by line looking for particular keywords in the lines to determine what you need to do. For your current example you can use the keyword "*File" to know when to create a new file to write data to. Just remember you want to close the previous BufferedWriter if it's currently writing to another file. Try this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
  {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Personal_Info.csv"));
      int fileNumber = 0;
      String csv = "CSV";
      BufferedWriter writer = null;

      while (scan.hasNextLine())
      {
          String line = scan.nextLine();
          if(line.contains("*File"))
          {
              fileNumber++;
              //check and make sure we close our previous writer
              if(writer != null)
                  writer.close();

              System.out.println("Creating a new file called: " + csv + fileNumber);
              writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\" + csv + fileNumber));
          }
          else if(writer != null)
          {
              writer.write(line + "\n");
          }
      }
      System.out.println("\n*************Process Complete*************");
      //Close the scanner 
      scan.close();
      if(writer != null)
          writer.close();
  }
```

Comment: This actually got the data that I needed in the file, but it was just in the same line, so ill just work on getting them in the different lines.

Comment: i added code to account for that, just added an additional new line character whenever we write to the file. good catch! when reading until nextLine() the end of line character gets removed. the fix should now output correctly @KhaosProgrammer

Comment: It is working as expected! Thanks for the help @RAZ_Muh_Taz

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the input file using a regex and writing each match to a new output file, something like this...

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Personal_Info.csv"));
    sc.useDelimiter("\\*File.*\n");

    int counter = 1;

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        try( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "CSV" + counter++ + ".txt")){
            out.println( sc.next() );
        }
    }
```